# how to convert 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: windows-server-2008

We have an IBM sytem x3650 MT 7979 running as a Vhost. I verified that the machine that we bought has a 64 bit architecture but it was configured as 32 bit.  the vhost has allocated 4 virtual servers that runs on 32 bit windows OS platform. If we want it configured as 64 bit, is there a detailed instruction on how to do this? Someone told me that we need to reinstall the hypervisor?

Answer (score 4):

You're going to have to reinstall.....

Comment: Yes, both the host OS and the VMs.  There are no cross-architecture in-place upgrades for Windows.